# How can I change the airline font color from white to black?

Tags: neovim, plugin-airline, plugin-solarized

[image]

I've seen someone who has these things (that I marked) colored as black, but as you can see mine are white. How can I have these things black ?

Comment: Instead of changing colors piecemeal you could get the [vim-airline-themes](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline-themes) plugin and choose a theme from the 100+ available that has dark text.

Comment: Not familiar with neo-vim but in vim one can configure this via editing the colorscheme. see : help user1. My colorscheme has entries such as 'hi user1 guifg=#000000` this sets the foreground to black. There are user1... user9 configurations.